# Adding a new targetConfigs property to an LWC in a managed package raises an error when upgrading

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package

I am updating an LWC in my dev org and adding a new property to be configured in the app builder however when I install the new version of the managed package which has more properties than the first version it raises an error.

> BearBonesTest: Invalid property [text2] in component [lwcManaged:bearBones]

This error only happens when the component is a part of the lightning page, If the component is not part of any lighting page then adding properties does not raise any error.
Is this the expected behavior and is there a way to resolve this?

v1 code for the lwc
html:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    {text1}
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

javasript:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class BearBones extends LightningElement {
    @api text1;
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage">
            <property name="text1" type="String" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

v2 code for the lwc
html:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    {text1}
    {text2}
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

javasript:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class BearBones extends LightningElement {
    @api text1;
    @api text2;
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage">
            <property name="text1" type="String" />
            <property name="text2" type="String" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Yup. Annoying, isn't it. Try adding a default for the new property.

Comment: @PhilW adding a default does not work. 
Is this a known issue?

Comment: I don't know if it is a "known issue", but it's certainly a problem. See my response.

Answer (score 0):

The other option which might be available to you depending if you have data is to uninstall the package from production and redeploy. Alternatively rename the component.

Comment: Suggestion to uninstall a package from production is a bit naïve since that means losing all data related to that package as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have also suffered issues in making changes like this; in our case we simply wanted to split out the flow screen target from the others ready to have a different set of properties for the latter compared with other targets (mainly because flow screens support array-based properties and others do not).

Even without making any changes to the actual list of properties, this caused the same type of problem you are having - any use of the component in the org prevents upgrade.

We ended up having to duplicate the LWC to a new name and make the changes to the duplicate. This means we now have cruft in our package and we will eventually delete the original LWC.

This is a systemic limitation on packaged LWCs that Salesforce really needs to sort out.